# Initialise empty\undef Dict while using abstract types

Tags: julia

I want to generate a Dict with undef values so I can later loop over the keys and fill in correct values. I can initialise an such a Dict using concrete types in the following way and it all works fine:

```
currencies = ["USD", "AUD", "GBP"]
struct example
    num::Float64
end
undef_array =  Array{example}(undef,3)
Dict{String,example}(zip(currencies, undef_array))
```

When my struct has an abstract type however I can still generate the undef array but I cannot create the dict. I get an error "UndefRefError: access to undefined reference"

```
abstract type abstract_num end
struct example2
    num::abstract_num
end
undef_array =  Array{example2}(undef,3)
Dict{String,example2}(zip(currencies, undef_array))
```

Although it is possible to create such a Dict with a concrete array:

```
struct numnum <: abstract_num
    num::Float64
end
def_array = [example2(numnum(5.0)), example2(numnum(6.0)), example2(numnum(4.5))]
Dict{String,example2}(zip(currencies, def_array))
```

### Question

My question is whether it is possible to generate a Dict with undef values of a type that relies on an abstract type? Is it is possible what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second (not working) example, `undef_array` is an array whos elements aren't initialized:

```
julia> undef_array =  Array{example2}(undef,3)
3-element Array{example2,1}:
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
```

The reason is that it's not possible to instantiate an object of type `example2` because your abstract type `abstract_num` (the type of the field of `example2`) doesn't have any concrete subtypes and, thus, can't be instantiated either. As a consequence even indexing `undef_array[1]` gives an `UndefRefError` and, hence, also `zip` won't work.

Compare this to the first case where the array elements are (arbitrarily) initialized:

```
julia> undef_array =  Array{example}(undef,3)
3-element Array{example,1}:
 example(1.17014136e-315)
 example(1.17014144e-315)
 example(1.17014152e-315)
```

and `undef_array[1]` works just fine.

Having said that, I'm not really sure what you try to achieve here. Why not just create a `mydict = Dict{String, example2}()` and fill it with content when the time comes? (As said above, you would have to define concrete subtypes of `abstract_num` first)

For performance reasons you should, in general, [avoid creating types with fields of an abstract type](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/performance-tips/#Avoid-fields-with-abstract-type-1).

Comment: Thanks for this crstnbr. My logic was that it would be faster to preallocate the space in memory for the whole dict and then fill it in rather than appending onto it repeatedly. So I guess this is not possible with abstract types here as the compiler doesn't know how much memory to set aside.

Comment: If you want to set aside memory in `Dict` type use `sizehint!` function. Note that `sizehint!` is meant only for growing dictionaries. By default `Dict` reserves `16` slots.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
a=Dict{String,Union{example3,UndefInitializer}}(currencies .=>undef)
```

However, for representing missing values the type `Missing` is usually more appropriate:

```
b=Dict{String,Union{example3,Missing}}(currencies .=>missing)
```

Please note that `typeof(undef)` yields `UndefInitializer` while `typeof(missing)` yields `Missing` - hence the need for `Union` types in the `Dict`. The dot (`.`) you can see above (`.=>`) is the famous Julia dot operator.

Moreover, I recommend to keep to Julia's naming conversion - `struct` and `DataType` names should start with a Capital Letter.

Last but not least, in your first example where concrete type `Float64` was given, Julia has allocated the array to some concrete address in memory - beware that it can contain some garbage data (have a look at console log below):

```
julia> undef_array =  Array{example}(undef,3)
3-element Array{example,1}:
example(9.13315366e-316)
example(1.43236026e-315)
example(1.4214423e-316)
```

Comment: Thanks for this Przemyslaw but it looks like this generates Dict{String,Union{example2,UndefInitializer}} or Dict{String,Union{example2,Missing}}  rather than Dict{String,example2}.

Comment: `undef` is not a undefined value, it is an instance of singleton type `UndefInitializer` that is used in array constructors.

Comment: @Stuart this is as close as you can get. You can not store `undef` in `Dict{String,example2}`
try

    `d = Dict{String,example2}()`

and then

    `d["key"] = undef  #this throws an error`

Hence, you need to explicitly state that you want to store `Missing` values within `Dict` values.

Comment: Thanks Przemyslaw. I have accepted the other answer as it more directly answers my question in saying it is not possible. Your answer is good though in giving the next best thing.